# Does Float Value break the behaivor of block elements?

Tags: html, css

Block Elements fill the entire width of the page by default,
so why float property makes these 2 blocks inline? Does float break with the behavior of the block elements?

```
 .block-text1 {
  width: 1000px;
  background-color: cyan;
  float: left;
}

.block-text2 {
  width: 1000px;
  background-color: blue;
  float: right;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3QrJ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual CSS rule that you describe as "Block Elements fill the entire width of the page by default" is [Block-level, non-replaced elements *in normal flow*](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visudet.html#blockwidth) exactly fill the entire width of their containing block, always. Floated elements are not in normal flow, so the rule simply does not apply to them.

[Floated elements have a completely separate width rule.](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visudet.html#float-width)

Answer (score -1):

Yes the float overides the display block element.

If you want the 2boxes displayed next to each other and complete fill the screen you can use CSS gridbox

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="box box1"></div>
  <div class="box box2"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
   grid-gap: 50px; //This is the vertical gap between the 2boxes.
   width: 100%;
}
```

If you want 1 box to be bigger you can change the 50% 50% to for example 30% 70%

Then if you want to display the boxes underneath eachother on smaller screen add this to CSS

```
@media (max-width: 900px) {
   .container {
     grid-templace-columns: 1fr;
   }
}
```

And if you do not want the 2boxes to display the complete with on the screen you can change the with of the .container element in your CSS.